# How do I install the Voids Wrath modpack on Windows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, minecraft-mods

I have been playing Minecraft on my Mac for a while now, and have been trying to find ways to mod my Minecraft and have failed on that notion, and have gotten a new Windows computer for getting my Minecraft modded.

I would like to know  how to install a modpack, called the Voids Wrath modpack, as well as where I can get this.

Comment: Related, if you want to try again on your Mac: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31363/how-do-you-install-minecraft-mods-on-a-mac

Comment: Related (ways to install mods that are easier than the normal way): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96483/is-there-a-faster-and-more-reliable-way-to-install-a-mod

Comment: Google is your friend. Googling `voids wrath mod pack` gives their site as the first link, and they have a prominent "Download" link to an automatic installer: http://voidswrath.com/index.php?id=download

Comment: @jeffreylin That computer runs Windows 8, not Android or Mac OS.

Comment: Now I'm all confused.

Comment: Close voters: I don't think questions about how to use and install mods are off-topic or 'too localized'. Also, [a Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one).

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the [Voids Wrath site](http://voidswrath.com/index.php?id=download), and you can install it by running the automated installer for Windows.