# Mods show up in menu but do not work in gameplay

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've downloaded the .jar of multiple mods.

Using Forge, I did the following:

'Get info' > I change the end of the file to .zip from .jar > open zip > place folder in `Application support/minecraft/mods` (Using a mac)

All mods I'm attempting to run show up in the mods list in the main menu, but when I play, none of the mods are actually active.

Answer (score 1):

Forge accepts mods in both `.zip` and `.jar` formats. You do not need to extract them anywhere. Simply plop them into your `mods` folder and restart Minecraft.

For more information about Forge and the installation of mods, check out [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164341/how-exactly-do-i-install-minecraft-mods-and-what-is-forge?rq=1).

[image: An example of a <code>mods</code> folder showing <code>.jar</code> files and various subfolders.]

Answer (score -1):

Some mods are client-only some mods are intended for servers and some require a server version and a client version to be installed to work properly in single player.

I would suggest you use a special launcher with pre-defined mod packs. They exist because producing a list of mods that work together with stability is a complicated task. Verifying that the correct mods exist and don't crash can take a long time and often a relationship with the developers of the mods.

Comment: Downvote with no feedback? What can I do to improve my answer?

Comment: It doesn't relate to their problem. They're breaking the mods by renaming and unpacking them and just need to be told to stop that.

Comment: Ah, that is well spotted! Good work. Thanks for the feedback as well.