# Is there a Pixelmon Linux Tutorial?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-pixelmon

I want to install a Pixelmon server on a Linux.

I have the following files:

- forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.1902-1.8.9-universal.jar
- minecraft_server.1.10.2.jar
- Pixelmon-1.8.9-4.2.7-universal.jar

I am unable to find a tutorial online to launch the commands necessary.

Is there a tutorial I can follow?

**EDIT:**  I should have specified earlier I needed a "headless" server tutorial.

Comment: Duplicate of [How exactly do I install Minecraft mods and what is Forge?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164341/how-exactly-do-i-install-minecraft-mods-and-what-is-forge?noredirect=1&lq=1). Unfortunately I retracted my close vote before realizing that, so can't close it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Version

Pixelmon 4.2 requires 1.8.9 with Forge version 11.15.1.1749 or later.

## Prerequisites

- Basic command-line knowledge
- A Linux Server.  I'm hosting one on a **[Microsoft Azure Server Basic A2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/)**

**NOTE:**  I first tried a *Basic A0* server but that was not powerful enough

- Java 1.8 To check the default you can run the following command:

  *java -version*

If 1.8 is not installed, you can try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177455/moving-from-jdk-1-7-to-jdk-1-8-on-ubuntu) one or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts).

Then, check the version again.  To change 1.8 to the default, run this:

*sudo update-alternatives --config java*

## Steps

1. Start with a GUI environment; this is required to get forge file.
2. Open browser and go to http://files.minecraftforge.net/
3. Click on the version you need; Pixelmon 4.2 requires 1.8.9.  FWIW, I got **forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.1902-1.8.9-installer.jar**:
   [image]
4. Get the forge installer jar to a folder on your Linux server; I used ftp
5. Go to the command line of Linux server
6. Navigate to the file with forge installer jar file
7. run the following command:

   **sudo java -jar forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.1902-1.8.9-installer.jar --installServer**
8. Delete installer file if you wish
9. Run this command to start forge:

   **sudo java -jar forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.1902-1.8.9-universal.jar nogui**

**NOTE:**  it will exception out b/c of the eula

10. Open newly created eula.txt (e.g. **sudo nano eula.txt**)  and set "eula=true"
11. Navigate to mods folder:  **cd mods**
12. Get pixelmon file:

**sudo wget http://download.nodecdn.net/containers/pixelmon/core/Pixelmon-1.8.9-4.2.7-universal.jar**

13. Re-run forge: **sudo java -jar forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.1902-1.8.9-universal.jar nogui**

Credit [to this link](https://blog.za3k.com/running-a-forge-server-on-headless-linux/) and MCCCS's answer to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This video should help.

Also you won't need minecraft_server.1.10.2.jar, Forge and

your Pixelmon is 1.8.9, not 1.10.2

Comment: +1 b/c this was helpful.  How come everybody's got a video tutorial these days?  Simple blog post would suffice.